# Coloring second half of vertex set (bipartite graph)

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I have a bipartite graph $G=((V_1,V_2),E)$ and colors $C_1$ for the vertices in $V_1$. Additionally, I know that for some $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $k<n$, $|V_1|=\binom{n}{k}$, $|V_2|=\binom{n}{k-1}$ and every vertex in $V_1$ has degree $k$ and every vertex in $ V_2$ has degrés $n-(k-1)$.
I want to determine a minimal coloring $C_2$ of $V_2$ such that the union of $C_1$ and $C_2$ is a coloring of $G$.

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem. Intuitively, I would start by coloring the uncolored vertices with $C_1$ until I encounter a conflict but I do not know how to frame this in a general setting. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. If $G$ is bipartite then it can be colored with just two colors, no?

Comment: Yes, a bipartite graph can be colored with two colors, each partition carrying one color. But now I have a set of colors given for one partition which contains more then one color, e.g., $v\in V_1$ is blues, $w\in V_1$ is blue and $u\in V_1$ is green. And now I want to color the other side such that no two vertices have the same color. The obvious upper bound  for the total number of colors is two times the colors of $ V_1$ but I hope to do better Given the degree regularity.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want to color the other side such that no two vertices have the same color?

Comment: @Jfischer Even after your comment, it's not very clear what needs to be done.

If the vertices of $V_1$ are already colored, then it is enough to color the vertices of $V_2$ with the same color that does not coincide with any color of $C_1$. As a result, the graph will be correctly colored (i.e. adjacent vertices have different colors) and $|C_2|=1$.

Comment: Yes, that is true. In my head it sounded differently. The question is: do I have to add another color to $C_1$ to color the whole graph or is $C_1$ sufficient?

Comment: @Jfischer It depends on the coloring of $V_1$. The vertices of $V_2$ will not interfere with each other, so it's simply a question of whether any vertex in $V_2$ is adjacent to vertices of every color used in $V_1$.